# Bulk API v2.0 Master Detail Record Field Import Failed

Tags: master-detail, bulk-api

I am going to trying and summarize this as well as I can.

My standard object "Contact" has an external Id field called "Client ID". This is the unique identifier for a contact/customer.

I also have a custom object called "Products". I have tried to create a master look-up field that would link "Products" to "Contact". The field in "Products" is called "Client_Id__c, when I try to upload the CSV through the Bulk API V2.0

When I try to use the Bulk API v2.0 to upload this product information, I get the below error

> "MALFORMED_ID:Client ID: id value of incorrect type:
> 98305:Client_ID__c --"

From my research this is suggesting that the malformed ID is because I need to use the salesforce ID and not the external id that I have listed on the "Contact"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use the `Client_ID__c` field because that is a lookup field to contact.

You need to rename that lookup field to something like Contact or Customer.  Then you need to create a text field in the Product object to contain the contact external ID.  Finally you need to set up relationship field in the header row, per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm).

> If the child object has a custom field with an API Name of
> Mother_Of_Child__c that points to a parent custom object and the
> parent object has a field with an API Name of External_ID__c, use the
> column header Mother_Of_Child__r.External_ID__c to indicate that
> you're using the parent object's External ID field to uniquely
> identify the Mother Of Child field. To use a relationship name in a
> column header, replace the __c in the child object's custom field with
> __r.